# nvd3 chart showing grayscale

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 for the fist time and I'm having a tough time with the example found [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBarHorizontal.html).

My issue, is that none of the colors are actually showing.... instead I'm getting varying shades of gray (insert 50 shades of grey joke here). This is what I have in my `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="nv.d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="nv.d3.css">
```

My chart is just the standard horizontal bar chart with their data from the example linked above.... I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong but if anyone has a suggestion let me know.

Thanks as always.

Comment: Did you copy the CSS?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I saved the css locally from the nvd3 site. I just took the link out and the chart was completely smushed and bad looking.... so I know that the css is being linked properly

Comment: I think there's a common.css as well, which you seem to be missing. Try downloading the *entire* example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the non-minified nvd3 script corrected the issue.